# Check whether list element is greater than previous elements

Tags: python

I have a list like this in Python:

```
mylist = [13, 8, 7, 5, 6, 3, 9]
```

I would like to check for each element of the list, whether it is greater or equal to the previous elements. If This is true I want to add 1 and check whether it is equal to a prior element. If this happens add numbers til it is not true anymore.

I hope you can understand, what I want to archive. The output for mylist would be

```
outputlist = [13, 8, 7, 5, 9, 3, 10]
```

so the `6` from `mylist` is greater than `5` so it adds `1`, now it is `7`, which already exists. So it adds another `1` (value = `8`) and another `1` (value = `9`).

the "9" from the initial list is equal to the fresh calculated 9, so it adds 1.

Note: order is important, so sorting `mylist` is not an option.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? SO is not a code writing service, please show your coding efforts and errors

Comment: By *already exists* you mean *anywhere in the list* or only *anywhere before that value*?

Comment: How can it be equal to a prior element after adding one, if it was (by transitivity) already greater than all the prior elements before? Ah, now I get it...

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters: i meant anywhere before that value.

@ tobias_k: the list could also be [9, 9, 9] so the output has to be [9,10,11]

Comment: This smells a bit like an assignment/homework?

Comment: @James Mills 
It is not, it is part of a Probability proportional to size sampling algorithm, I would like to code in Python to make it accesible via  a VBA-command.

Comment: Got a link that describes this algo?

Comment: @James Mills i will edit my initial post with my current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very pretty, but I did not find a shorter way to do this. Seems to work, though.

```
def magic(lst):
    lst = lst[:] # create copy
    seen = set() # prior values as set
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if any(lst[i] >= x for x in lst[:i]): # greter/equal than any prior
            lst[i] += 1      # first increment
            while lst[i] in seen:
                lst[i] += 1  # increment more
        seen.add(lst[i])     # add to prior set
    return lst
```

Example:

```
>>> magic([9, 9, 9, 9])
[9, 10, 11, 12]
>>> magic([13, 8, 7, 5, 6, 3, 9])
[13, 8, 7, 5, 9, 3, 10]
```

Comment: @JamesMills Whops... give me a second... did not get that it is enough if it is greater/equal to `any` prior element. Fixed now.

Comment: This is already very helpful i will try to solve it for my problem.

Thank you very much!